# Проблема с установкой дельта модуля в формате .upd на битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

Есть nulled версия решения для импорта товаров с сайтов поставщиков. Проблема в том что она в формате .upd и я не понимаю как ее установить. Нашел скрипт который патчит ядро битрикса и чтото там делает дальше, но с ним решение тоже не устанавливается. Был бы очень признателен если бы ктото подкинул вариант как это решить.

Comment: https://dzen.ru/a/XsQn3qtS2Uvgrc_q